# AVD Manager Android Emulator - Cannot find installed application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I just installed .apk file on my emulated android. I installed it via ADB and i can't find this app on my emulated android. When i'm trying to install it again, i'm getting error: 
`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]` but i'm still can't find this app on emulated android.

What can i do? Thank you for help

Edit: Right now i've got on my emulated android MyApplication icon. When i'm running it, only there's text "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

Select your virtual device and click Start There's an option called Wipe Data for you to clear all user data.

Comment: I wiped data and installed app again, but only appeared icon of MyApplication and "Hello World" text in.

Comment: So the first problem is solved. I don't think this is an issue with emulator. Try Run->clean and rerun.If it still displays just hello World, you have to check your code again. Otherwise, just try it on a real device if possible.

Comment: _Try Run->clean and rerun._ - I don't understand, what i need to clean?

Comment: To run your app, Open your project in Android studio, click run->clean and rerun from menu bar.(or ctrl+F5)

Comment: I found problem, it was just big bug in my code. Thank you for reply :)